# Crontab not able to Run jar file

Tags: java, jar, cron

By running:

```
00 01 * * 1 root /usr/bin/java -jar /home/export/export.jar
```

Output: the scheduler will fail to wake up.

Then I changed it to:

`00 01 * * 1 root /usr/bin/java -jar /home/export/export.jar > /home/export/cron.log 2>&1`

It worked!

Can I do this without exporting to the file - `cron.log`?
I did used log4j to log the process;
`cron.log` is a duplicate log for me.

Comment: Is your mail setup correctly?  Perhaps having to mail the result is blocking cron...

Answer (score 1):

You can replace with /dev/null , as in:

```
00 01 * * 1 root /usr/bin/java -jar /home/export/export.jar > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank for the help.
I found there have a bug on the winscp which need a space after command.
If edited with putty, it no need extra space.